# How can I delete a set of records from sql table

Tags: sql

I have a table with the name column containing values like `'arthur_01', 'arthur_02', 'arthur_03'...'arthur_10'` and many other values.

Is there a way to delete all the `'arthur_0x'` in one query?
I know that the `BETWEEN` operator takes a range, but is there a way for it to take in a range where half the string is numeric?

Comment: What RDBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle,...) are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the LIKE operator: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'arthur_0%';
```

This solution makes somse assumptions about what data is beyond 'arthur_0.....'. Otherwise you may need RDBS specific functions.

Answer (score 3):

There are different approaches to this and unfortunately most of them are vendor specific.

One approach is to extract the character of interest and compare to target value

```
DELETE FROM table1
 WHERE SUBSTRING(column_name, 9, 1) = x;
```

or for a range of values

```
DELETE FROM table1
 WHERE SUBSTRING(column_name, 9, 1) BETWEEN x AND y
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28d7c/1)** demo (MySQL)
Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd25b4/1)** demo (SQL Server)

**Note:** *the drawback of this approach is that the optimizer won't be able to use any indices you might have on this column.*

---

Another approach is to leverage pattern matching, but it's not implemented the same way in different RDBMSes.

In SQL Server for example you can do

```
DELETE FROM table1
 WHERE column_name LIKE 'arthur_0[345]%';
```

Which will effectively delete any rows with values in `column_name` that start with 
`arthur_03` or `arthur_04` or `arthur_05`.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a45e00/1)** demo

Same thing in MySQL might look like

```
DELETE FROM table1
 WHERE column_name RLIKE '^arthur_0[345]';
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f501/1)** demo